# Best way to display total size of NSData before written to disk

Tags: ios, objective-c, byte, nsdata

I have a problem to find out estimated size of file size BEFORE it is written. Basically I have mutableArray of NSDictionary that I allow user to select.

Upon user selection, I'd like to show to user how big is the total size of the data he selected.

This is my **pseudo code:**

```
__block int totalsize = 0;
[mutableArray enumerate:{
   NSData *data = [NSPropertySerialize dictionary];
   totalsize += [data length];
}];

label.text = [NSString string:totalsize/1024.0/1024.0];
```

The problem is there is some decrepancies in the totalsize and the actual
written data to app sandbox.

Is there an accurate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please Use This Code It will be Help You Out

```
NSData *data=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mutableArray options:(NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted) error:&error];

NSLog(@"Size Of Data In Bytes:-%lu",(unsigned long)data.length);
```

Comment: This is not answering my question. I want to know how to find out the data size of file written before it is written.